# How to modify or add new Nginx configuration in Tomcat AWS Elastic beanstalk (Spring Boot Application)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had a Spring Boot Application and it was deployed in the AWS Elastic beanstalk (Tomcat server). It was a war deployment.

I need to change the Nginx configuration. Need to add `client_max_body_size 50M;` to the configuration. While checking the AWS Documentation found a way to modify the configuration via placing config file in `.platform/nginx` location in the project root. I tried and it was not working.

Then I found these files are not picking while **war** creation. I can explain the build process too.

1. Code build will generate the war file
2. Uploading this war to S3
3. Creating Application version (By uploading this war to the ELB)
4. Pointing the that version to the elastic beanstalk environment.

Can anyone help me to find a solution to change the nginx config in ELB for war deployment?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Amazon Linux version 2, you need to put nginx config into following path:

`.platform/nginx/conf.d/config.conf`

If you are using Amazon Linux version 1, location should be:

`.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/config.conf`

This folder (.platform/.ebextension) should be inside Zip file (which contains your war/jar and this .platform/.ebextension folder) to work.

Comment: Currently I am just uploading the war file not zip. So can i zip these folder and the war to a .zip then try to upload? Is the zip will deploy our war file in the server?

Comment: since its Elastic Beanstalk it will accept .zip quite fine.
Also, you can make maven/gradle scripts to put .war file into special folder (lets say /deploy) which will have this configuration folder and from there use `eb deploy -l 1.0.0`

Comment: I changed the war name to ROOT.war and I zipped the war, along with the .platform folder and uploaded to ELB. Works fine for me.